# How to properly design RestController for spring REST API with JPA?

Tags: spring, rest, jpa

I don't know how to properly design the architecture for a movie database web app backend.

I have a Movie Entity which has a list of Genre Entity and a Map of Actor Entitiys with their role in the movie:

```
// ...

@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String director;
    private Date releaseDate;
    private Long posterId;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "MOVIE_GENRES",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "MOVIE_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "GENRE_ID"))
    private Set<Genre> genres = new HashSet<>();

    // TODO how to rename value column (CAST -> ACTOR_ID)
    @OneToMany
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "ACTOR_ROLE")
    private Map<String, Actor> cast = new HashMap<>();

    // ...
}
```

I also have a REST Controller for Movies:

```
@RestController
public class MovieController {

    private MovieRepository repository;

    public MovieController(MovieRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/movies")
    public List<Movie> all() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/api/movies")
    Movie newMovie(@RequestBody Movie newMovie) {
        return repository.save(newMovie);
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/movies/{id}")
    Movie one(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new MovieNotFoundException(id));
    }

    @PutMapping("/api/movies/{id}")
    Movie replaceMovie(@RequestBody Movie newMovie, @PathVariable Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id)
                .map(movie -> {
                    movie.setTitle(newMovie.getTitle());
                    movie.setDirector(newMovie.getDirector());
                    movie.setReleaseDate(newMovie.getReleaseDate());
                    movie.setGenres(newMovie.getGenres());
                    movie.setCast(newMovie.getCast());
                    return repository.save(movie);
                })
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    newMovie.setId(id);
                    return repository.save(newMovie);
                });
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/api/movies/{id}")
    void deleteMovie(@PathVariable Long id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

This is how it looks when I call `/api/movies`. I receive all the genre and cast information too, for every movie. Is this okay? I don't even need all this information when getting a list of all movies.

If I follow REST principles, shouldn't I get the cast via `/api/movies/{id}/cast`? I know how to add another @RestMapping that returns only the cast but it doesn't change the fact that the cast will still be included in every `/api/movies` call.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "The Matrix",
    "director": null,
    "releaseDate": null,
    "posterId": 1,
    "genres": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Science Fiction"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Action"
        }
    ],
    "cast": {
        "Agent Smith": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Hugo Weaving",
            "gender": "MALE",
            "dateOfBirth": "1960-04-04"
        },
        "Morpheus": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Laurence Fishburne",
            "gender": "MALE",
            "dateOfBirth": "1961-07-30"
        },
        "Thomas A. Anderson / Neo": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Keanu Reeves",
            "gender": "MALE",
            "dateOfBirth": "1964-09-02"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question: You should do a little more of a "deep dive" on this to understand what's going on. It's not a matter of REST design in this case. I don't know if you were surprised to see the cast included with movie information but you should be.

Your code `return repository.findById(id) …` seems clearly intended to retrieve only movie information but you notice you are also getting the cast. Did you do print the sql statements from the `Spring Data Jpa` system to see if it was acting the way you expected? I suspect not, because if you had you would probably have noticed that several sql statements are being generated. The first for the movie and then subsequent statements for the cast.

Once you traced down why you are getting multiple sql statements you will find that the statements are coming from the Entity->JSON conversion. This means that when your service returns the `Movie` entity the spring framework needs to convert it to JSON to send it over the wire and that code is walking the object graph. The object graph are the instances of the entities you have created in the JVM when you queried the database. Since you have mapped the `Movie/Cast` relationship the movie object includes possible references to the cast and when the JSON transform code does a get on the cast property JPA detects that an issues another request since spring framework is still holding the database transaction in scope. If the transaction was out of scope you would have gotten a `LazyInitialization` exception. All this you should research a little more so that you understand it.

So, how to you go about making a better design? You are at least two possibilities that come to mind. First, you could remove the `cast` mapping. Why do you think you need to have the `cast` as a collection within the movie? If you want to get the cast for a movie you could simply call `castRepository.findByMovie(movie)` and get the list. Second, you could use a DTO, or Data Transfer Object, which is a separate POJO that defines what you want your REST interface to actually return. In this case it could be a `MovieDto` class that is the same as the `Movie` entity class but without the cast property. Then you would change your `movieRepository` to have an method defined as `Optional<MovieDto> findById(Long id)` and spring-data-jpa will use the [Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) feature to translate your `Movie` entity into a `MovieDto` object automagically.

Using the [Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) feature would be my recommended approach. DTO's are meant for "views" for the business layer of your application. Different consumers of your service might want different views into the world of movies. Casting agents might want a list of all movies an actor appeared in while movie critics might want a list of cast as well as the movie and movie buffs might just want the details of a movie. All different DTOs, or views, for the same database. I would also carefully consider whether you actually need a `cast` mapping. I notice you have a `cast = new HashMap<>();` code segment that creates a `HashMap` for the movie side of the relationship but you shouldn't need that and in the typical read use case it will be thrown away stressing the garbage collector. Finally I notice that you defined cast as a Map but why did you do that? What is going in the key of the map, the movie name? That's bad design. Actors can appear in more than one movie and movies can have more than one actor so you should have a many-to-many relationship.

Finally, this is why "is this good design" questions are frowned upon in SO. The answers are complicated and usually opinionated and not what SO is meant for.